# Rotation issue for Portrait Mode in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have enabled all the mode in info.plist, When I rotate my device from portrait mode to Landscape. DidRotate and WillRotate method is called. But when I rotate from  landscape mode to portrait, None of them is called. Please lemme know what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after resetting the simulator. I guess it was a random issue